# Proguard with spring boot - integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, proguard

I'm using ProGuard for spring-boot app obfuscation. It's working fine, resulting jar is builded and is running well, without any issues.

To achieve that I used a few tweaks:

- custom beanNameGenerator

  ```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApp.class)
            .beanNameGenerator((beanDefinition, beanDefinitionRegistry) -> beanDefinition.getBeanClassName())
            .run(args);
       }
  ```
- preservation of Autowired, Qualifier, Bean, Value annotation members,
- preservation of main method
- keepattributes switch with Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
- dontshrink, dontoptimize, useuniqueclassmembernames, adaptclassstrings, dontusemixedcaseclassnames options

However,  integration tests (@SpringBootTest) broke with error (they are running fine when builded without proguard):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test.
```

After include of main entry class (@SpringBootTest(classes=MainApp.class)) :

```
2019-09-11 19:00:13,178 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6b04acb2] to prepare te
st instance [com.xxx.xxx.it.ExternalIT@258274cb]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.xxx.a.a.b' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

And so on.

Is there any way to make it work, other than creating new profile for performing tests without obfuscating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> preservation of Autowired, Qualifier, Bean, Value annotation members,

You did the right thing here,you need to preserve all attribute

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
```

however It's not the cause of your problem,Spring does the autowiring byType and  in my experience post obfuscation such issue comes of not finding bean of type.

You need to tweak your code, use your annotation with name like

> @Component("yourComponentName")

instead of

> @Component

**same with bean and Service and other annotation**

and wherever you use then use `@Qualifier("nameofbeanorService")`

and since you preserved annotation attribute your application will work smooth.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Hovewer, extracting BeanNameGenerator to separate Bean and registering it in @ComponentScan of main class worked.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting BeanNameGenerator to separate Bean and registering it in @ComponentScan in @SpringBootApplication, instead of inlining it in SpringApplicationBuilder in main method made things working.